# Vuex: Why is my array initialized with an element Observer before making any mutations?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array in my initial state initialized to an empty array.

```
const state = {tmpArray = []}
```

When I first access the state, from anywhere, by using getters, using mapState on a Vue component or even printing it while a vuex action is being dispatched before making a mutation, the variable tmpArray shows an array with an element Observer within it (If I print it with console.log) or shows an empty object (if I use vue dev tools)

Using vue dev tools:

```
> tmpArray: Array[1]
  > 0: Object (empty)
```

Using console.log:

```
[{…}, __ob__: Observer]
     0: 
       __ob__: Observer
          dep: Dep {id: 1195, subs: Array(0)}
          value: __ob__: Observer
                   dep: Dep {id: 1195, subs: Array(0)}
                   value: __ob__: Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
                          __proto__: Object
                   vmCount: 0
                   __proto__: Object
                 __proto__: Object
          vmCount: 0
          __proto__: Object
       __proto__: Object
       length: 1
       __ob__: Observer {value: Array(1), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
       __proto__: Array
```

I get this just by accessing the array anywhere by doing this:

```
state.tmpArray
```

This array is used to view info on a table and I'm getting an empty row because of this.

I am not making any mutation to this state before accessing and showing it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This Observer is the way Vue implements its reactivity mechanism and watches for mutations. Even if you do not make any mutation - Vue must still inject these Observers or otherwise there will be no reactivity.

Comment: I understand this, Vue needs observers to implement reactivity. But It happens even without making any mutations to the array and it's making the table to have always an additional row. I mean, this item keeps being an observer forever. If I add more data to the array, this data is displayed on the table with its real info, but this random observer is empty and never disappears.

Comment: Your array obviously contains an empty Object - you should investigate how the array is initialized and where does this empty Object come from.

Comment: That's was the very first thing that came to my mind and I have already checked it out. I will check it again in case I missed something out and I am actually making a mutation somewhere in the code. Anyway, does it occur to you any other thing that may be happening besides this? Thanks for your help!!

Comment: There are only 2 possibilities for this - either the state in the store is initialized with a non-empty array, or you have a mutation which pushes empty Object to this array.